# Is according to fit for my sentence?

Tags: adjectives

> I build my first project **according to** the web page http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html step by step.

Am I using *according to* correctly in my sentence?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I can't make sense of your sentence. What kind of "project" is your project? Why is it related to the steps on the Ask page? As it is, it's unclear, and it's a proofreading request. Either way, I think it's off-topic.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#creating-a-page-route-and-controller

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask , it is just a sample ,whatever url is the same meaning.

Comment: I disagree that "whatever url is the same meaning." You can easily confuse the reader by using a URL that has little to do with your question. On this site, people often follow links to get clarification. As a footnote, I think many people are unaware of how confusing ELL questions can be, and how much more confusing they can become by using fillers like _sth_, _X_ or a URL that has nothing to do with the rest of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of **according to** is correct since you used the steps / instructions from the web page.

> We made the cake **according to** the recipe.

Comment: One might say that this use of _according to_ is a bit confusing, because the URL isn't the guidance, it's merely the location of the guidance. Would we say, _We made our travel plans in accordance with the bus schedule_? Or _We made our travel plans in accordance with the times published in the bus schedule_? I don't know if I'd go so far as to call the O.P.'s original usage "incorrect," but it might be improved with some additional words, such as: _I built my first project according to **the guidance provided at** the web page._ (Not arguing with you here; just trying to flesh this out.)

Comment: @J.R. +1 For bringing up some good points.  I think the OP is basically using **according to** to mean **because of** or **due to**: "we made the cake **according to** the recipe". To me, **in accordance with** has the connotation of **in agreement with**, **In accordance** with generally accepted accounting principles". **According to** doesn't necessary mean one agrees with *something* and quite possibly one could be *forced to* as in **according to the law**. (cont'd)

Comment: I agree your "guidance" sentence is more specific as in "We made the cake according to ***the cookbook***" vs "We made the cake according to ***the recipe***", but I think most people wouldn't misunderstand where the guidance is located.  I do think it is said: "We made travel plans **according to** road conditions". In "we made travel plans **according to** the bus schedule" the actual "bus schedule times" is implicit and understood.

Comment: Rather than using "according to," I think I might say it this way: _I built my first project **by following the steps found at** the web page..._ (Of course, the O.P. didn't ask for a better way to word it, so that's why I'm leaving this as a comment instead of an answer. Perhaps "according to" can mean "by following the steps at," so everything's okay in the original.)